# How to make a key binding to the left shift?

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I have a Mac keyboard and trying to assign the backslash character to the "left shift + `" combination.

However the following code:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "S-`")                                                        
                'insert_backslash)                                                 

(defun insert_backslash ()                                                         
  (interactive)                                                                    
  (insert "\\"))
```

creates the binding only for the right shift key.
How do I assign it to the left shift instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does **`C-h k`** tell you when you use that key (press and hold Left Shift and hit **`` ` ``**)? It should tell you exactly what Emacs calls that key. Then use what it tells you as the arg to `kbd`.

Comment: ok, it prints ¬, so my code should be: (global-set-key (kbd "¬")                                                        
                'insert_backslash) instead